# Mac Mini Keeps freezing and have to manually power down and restart

Tags: mac, mac-mini, performance

I have a mac mini 2.3Ghz Intel Core i5 running 2GB 1333 MHz DDR3.  The mac keeps freezing.  Sometimes while I'm working on it, but often just when I leave it and it won't wake up and I have to hold down the power button to turn it off and then turn on again.  Any ideas on how to sort this?  Should I just upgrade the RAM or is it likely to be a different problem?  When it freezes nothing I try including force quit seems to work.  Thanks in advance, David

Comment: What's your Mac OS version?  When your Mac hangs, can you get any response from the system at all?  Mouse cursor movement onscreen?  Do the volume and monitor brightness keys produce the usual onscreen indicators?  Does the system time in the menu bar stop updating?  How often do you encounter these hangs?  About how long since the last reboot does a hang typically occur?

Comment: As Kyle notes, to successfully troubleshoot this, we need more info. Is there any pattern to when this happens? Have you made any changes to your system recently? It sounds like there's no [kernel panic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic#Mac_OS_X), but it would be a good idea to check the logs in Console.app for any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Mac mini. I tried different RAM, re-installed the OS, looked at system logs to try to figure out what was causing the problem. I got nowhere. Eventually I took it into the Apple Store to have a genius take a look, and at first it checked out fine. They kept it overnight and determined the logic board was bad. After a warranty replacement, it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I ran disk utility and repaired even though it said not necessary then I ran onyx latest version automatic fix and mine is working fine now!